# error: incompatible types: Object cannot be converted to String

Tags: java, arrays, collections

**error: incompatible types: Object cannot be converted to String**

```
import java.util.*; 
import java.io.*;

public class ArrayToCollection{
    public static void main(String args[])throws IOException{
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.println("How many elements you want to add to the array: ");
        int n = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
        String[] name = new String[n];
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
            name[i] = in.readLine();
        }
        List list = Arrays.asList(name); 
        System.out.println();
        for(String li: list){
            String str = li;
            System.out.print(str + " ");
       }
    }
}
```

How to fix this error? How to convert an object to string?
........................................................
........................................................

Comment: Do not use the raw type `List`. You want `List<String>`.

Comment: It works now.thank you.

Comment: No problem. I'm glad I could help.

Comment: @PaulBoddington Shouldn't a comment like this be an answer instead?

Comment: @Nier The trouble is it's an obvious duplicate. I'll find a relevant dupe and close it.